# Is possible to convert EBS-backed ami to s3-backed ami

Tags: amazon-ec2, amazon-web-services, amazon-ebs

I have an EBS AMI running Windows Server 2008.
Is possible to converter it to a S3 backed ami?

In ElasticFox, the "bundle into an S3 ami" option is grayed out.

If this is possible, how?
If this is not possible, why not?

Answer (score 1):

This has been answered by the AWS people on this [forum post](https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?threadID=40988).  For posterity's sake, here is Cindy@AWS's response:

> Windows Server 2008 AMIs are only
>   available for EBS-backed instances. 
>   It is not currently possible to save a
>   Windows Server 2008 instance into an
>   S3 AMI.  In order to save your
>   instance as an AMI, you should use
>   either the EC2 API tools command
>   ec2-create-image or (in the AWS
>   Management Console) choose "Create
>   Image":
>
> http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/creating-an-ami-ebs.html

Comment: So what about Linux ?

Comment: You should be able to follow the same instructions from the link.

Comment: The title of the article is: "Creating Amazon EBS-Backed AMIs."  The question is how to convert an EBS to a S3 AMI

Comment: The post explains that this is not possible to *convert* from EBS to S3 for the AMI.  What the post explains, is, you can create an S3-backed AMI by launching the EBS backed image, using `ec2-create-image`, and uploading this to S3.  So its not a conversion process--its a "rebuilding a mostly identical image and uploading said image to an S3 backed AMI."  I'm not quite sure what you're confused about here, but I would like to make sure its clear. :)